# What does Bus error: 10 mean? And how to fix this error

Tags: c, string, bus-error

below is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* get_string(char* question);

int main(void)
{
    char* name = get_string("Enter a name:");
    printf("%s\n", name);
    return 0;
}

char* get_string(char* question)
{
    printf("%s", question);
    char* input;
    scanf("%s", input);
    return input;
}
```

It compiles just fine without any warning or errors, but when I run the code I got this

```
Bus error: 10
```

Comment: You have a pointer `input`, but *where does it point?*

Comment: And if you don't get a *warning* from that code, then you need to enable more warnings. With GCC or Clang use at least `-Wall`, and they *will* warn you about the issue.

Comment: As to what `Bus error: 10` means:  "SIGBUS (10) / Bus error 10 means a signal sent to an application if an attempts is made to access memory outside of its address space. This may be due to bad pointer that has an invalid address in it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function `get_string()` you try to take input using `scanf()` using a uninitialized pointer called `input`.

Since `input` points to nothing, reading into it causes undefined behaviour.

To fix it you should allocate memory for your string:

```
char *input = malloc(sizeof(char) * input_size);
```

Also don't forget to `free()` your `input` buffer when you are done using it:

```
free(input);
```

Comment: You also should explain that freeing `input` at the end of `get_string` (which is what the OP probably will understand) will just trigger anothe problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My code is working now.